# two sequences asymptotic, then their differences go to zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

One last problem before I go to sleep, I must be too tired to see this one. This is another qual type question.

Let $\{x_{n}\}$ and $\{y_{n}\}$ be sequences of real numbers such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

$y_{n} \neq 0$ and $\frac{x_{n}}{y_{n}} \rightarrow 1$.
Show if either sequence is bounded, that $(x_{n}-y_{n}) \rightarrow 0$

I'm probably the most unclear as to where boundedness comes into this problem, even if I suppose from the get go that one of them is bounded arbitrarily.

I have so far that $\left| \frac{x_{n}}{y_{n}}-1\right|$=$\left|\frac{x_{n}-y_{n}}{y_{n}}\right|$, and I feel like I'm halfway there because the numerator of that expression is exactly what I want, however the denominator is a little pesky.

Comment: To find a counterexample if the boundedness condition fails, take $x_n = n+1$ and $y_n = n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.  Now, just take $-M \le y_n \le M$.

$$0 \le \frac{|x_n - y_n|}{M} \le \frac{|x_n - y_n|}{|y_n|} \to 0$$

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks for the catch.

Comment: I was curious if this move was valid, now what about $x_{n}$ being bounded? We should be able to do something in either case and not have to take the strategy that Jonas suggested.

Comment: @DavidSacco This doesn't impose any condition concerning boundedness on $x_n$.  It's just an application of the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @David, Andrew: One still has to show that $(y_n)$ is bounded if it is only assumed that $(x_n)$ is bounded, in order to apply this strategy.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Perhaps that's not necessary.  You could show that $x_n \ne 0$ for all but finitely many $n$ and then take $\frac{y_n}{x_n} \to 1$ and apply this strategy as well.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon: Nice alternative!

Answer (score 2):

- Prove that if $(a_n)$ is a sequence that converges to $0$ and $(b_n)$ is a bounded sequence, then $(a_nb_n)$ converges to zero.
- Apply this to $a_n=\dfrac{|x_n-y_n|}{|y_n|}$ and $b_n=|y_n|$.
- Note that because it says "either sequence," you should include proof that $(y_n)$ must be bounded even if it is initially only assumed that $(x_n)$ is bounded.

To see why boundedness is important, note that $n$ is asymptotically equivalent to $n+1$, for example.  Or $n^2$ is asymptotically equivalent to $(n+1)^2$, and there the difference even diverges to $\infty$.